# How to start Emacs daemon when Windows start-up and kill it before Windows Shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-10, emacs

On Microsoft Windows, the time of opening my GNU Emacs (with tons of plugins) are non-trivial, so I decided to use Emacs Daemon. However, I cannot figure out a way to open and close the daemon automatically. I need to gracefully close emacs since I want it to save the recent files and other unsaved buffers for org agenda.

The things I tried:

- Group policy scripts: not working, even though the scripts works if I call them manually
- Running the script [on Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration#toc7) has no effect